# How to split/separate input text in two search boxes

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, search

I have a form of two `input search boxes` and when I type text into the first `search box`, it also copies the text that I've typed from the first `search box` to the second one.

Here is my form for the `search boxes`

```
<form style="margin-bottom: 0px;">
    <label>Date From :</label>
    <input class="search" type="search" data-column="0">
    &nbsp;
    <label>To :</label>
    <input class="search" type="search" data-column="0">
</form>
```

Here's my `table`

```
<table class="tablesorter table table-bordered table-condensed" id="cLoanOut" style="table-layout: fixed;">
    <colgroup>
        <col width="110">
        <col width="130">
        <col width="50">
        <col width="60">
        <col width="90">
    </colgroup>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Date Ordered</th>
            <th>Order No.</th>
            <th>Total Item(s)</th>
            <th>Total Amount</th>
            <th>Order Status</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

And my `PHP` to show rows

```
case "display":
    $sql = "SELECT * from tb_empgroc_master";
//            $myData = mysql_query($sql,$con);
    $result = $atecCoop->query($sql);
//            mysql_close($con);

    $html = ''; $ctr = 0;
    if ($result->num_rows){
        while ($row = $result->fetch_object()){
        $id = $row->empgrocmstID;
        $date_ordered = date("m-d-Y");
        $order_no = date($row->order_no);
        $total_items = number_format($row->total_items);
        $total_amount = number_format($row->total_amount,2);
        $order_status = wordwrap($row->order_status);
        $Order = $row->empgrocmstID;

        $html .= "<tr id='$id'>";
        $html .= "<td class='date_ordered' style='text-align:center'>$date_ordered</td>";
        $html .= "<td class='order_no' style='text-align:center'>$order_no</td>";
        $html .= "<td class='total_items' style='text-align:right'>$total_items</td>";
        $html .= "<td class='total_amount' style='text-align:right'>$total_amount</td>";
        $html .= "<td id='$Order' class='order_status' style='text-align:center'>$order_status</td>";
        $html .= "</tr>";
        }
    }
    echo $html;
break;
```

And here's my `script` to `filter search` the `tr` on the first column which is `Date_Ordered`

```
$.tablesorter.filter.bindSearch( $('#cLoanOut'), $('.search') );
```

I want to filter dates `from and to` in `date_ordered` and it works but the problem is when I type on the `search box` `(Date From)` it also input and copies the text that I've typed from `(Date From)` to `search box` `(To)`.

I tried to put some `Id's` in each `search box` and still the same. Also I've changed their `class`. But still the same. Like this.

```
<form style="margin-bottom: 0px;">
    <label>Date From :</label>
    <input id="From" class="search" type="search" data-column="0">
    &nbsp;
    <label>To :</label>
    <input id="To" class="Searches" type="search" data-column="0">
</form>

$.tablesorter.filter.bindSearch( $('#cLoanOut'), $('.search') ); // or $('#From')
$.tablesorter.filter.bindSearch( $('#cLoanOut'), $('.Search') ); // or $('#To')
```

Still the same.. But when I changed of course the data-column of `search box` `(To)` They text input are totally separated. But I want those two to filter on the first column which is `Date Ordered` that's why they're `data-column="0"`

Thanks for your help.

This is my problem

```
Date from: asdasdasd To: asdasdasd
```

Comment: i can not understand what's your problem.

Comment: When I type asdasdasd on `Date from:`, It also types on the second search box which is `To:`

Comment: But you say you made it like this in the beginning of your post

Comment: Now, I'm the one who can't understand you...

Comment: use `keyup` or `keypress`... then get the value of the firstTextbox and put it on a `.text` property of the 2nd textBox.

Comment: @Micaela put your code on a jsfiddle example

Comment: Voting close based on "unclear what you're asking". Make sure you present a clear question, it has 0 value for future users.

Answer (score 0):

If i understood right you have to change the form like this:

```
<form style="margin-bottom: 0px;">
   <label>Date From :</label>
   <input id="from" class="search" type="search">
   &nbsp;
   <label>To :</label>
   <input id="to" class="search" type="search">
   <input class="realSearch" type="hidden" data-column="0"/>
</form>
```

and apply some javascript, see in the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/p9pkv7yu/1/